# How training loop for 1 epoch is taking way longer than all batches of trainloader loop execution time?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, gpu, cluster-computing

**I have following specification:**
AMD 32 core processors
NVIDIA GPU Tesla V100 16 GB gpu.

**To debug/test:**
I have used: only **1 GPU**.

My dataset is: **Imagenet-1k 2012**

Batch size: **32**

using following details:

`python train.py --batch-size 32 --gpu-no 1 --epochs 10`

```
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate, weight_decay=weight_decay)
scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.CosineAnnealingLR(optimizer, T_max=num_epochs, eta_min=0.0002)
```

I am trying to debug following part (training) of the code:

```
for epoch in range(start_epoch, num_epochs + 1):
        model.train()
        running_loss = 0.0
        correct_predictions = 0
        # Start time for the current epoch
        start_time = time.time()
        for images, labels in train_loader:
            start_time_l = time.time()
            images = images.cuda()
            labels = labels.cuda()
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            outputs = model(images)
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
            print(loss.device)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            running_loss += loss.item() * images.size(0)
            # Calculate the number of correct predictions
            _, predicted = torch.max(outputs, 1)
            correct_predictions += (predicted == labels).sum().item()
            end_time = time.time()
            # Calculate elapsed time for the current iteration
            iteration_time = end_time - start_time_l
            print(f"Time: {iteration_time:.4f} seconds", flush=True)
        epoch_loss = running_loss / len(train_subset)
        train_accuracy = correct_predictions / len(train_subset)
        # Update the learning rate for the next epoch
        scheduler.step()
        
        print(f'Epoch [{epoch+1}/{num_epochs}], Loss: {epoch_loss:.4f}, Train Accuracy: {train_accuracy:.4f}', flush=True)
```

I tried with `nvidia-smi`  and got following:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8Xod.png)

So, only 3206MiB / 16384MiB is in use.

Moreover, I got output (time for each iteration) for batch loop as:

```
cuda:0
Time: 0.0638 seconds
```

***However, finally even after 10 hours of execution:***
**I still have not gotten even the print result of first (1st) epoch.**

When a single loop computation is only taking `0.0638 seconds` , how can nearly ~ 52000 iterations (32 batches for ~ 1,200,000 training images) take more than 10 hours? And, yet can not give result for first epoch.

Is this expected? If not, where am I wrong in this inference?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is solved from my side:

Apparent understanding of mine was following:

CPU is taking way longer time (~ `1.5 seconds` for each batch loop) to transfer batches of trainloader to GPU. Surely, GPU is superfast (in this case for 32 batch size only ~ `0.06 second` for each batch loop) and hence it has to seat idle no matter how powerful it is. Because, CPU is unable to catch speed of GPU computation.

*To solve the problem:*

One has to instantiate `trainloader` with multiple number of workers (`num_workers > 1`). Basically, this is multiprocessing of CPU. The worker is essentially a separate process running in parallel on our CPU cores.
In summary, the number of workers controls how many parallel processes are used for data loading and preprocessing, making more efficient use of our CPU cores.

```
train_loader = DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=num_workers)
```

The number of workers one should use for a DataLoader in PyTorch depends on various factors, including the specific dataset, the complexity of the data loading operations, and the available CPU cores.

*Following are the factors to be considered:*

1. Number of CPU Cores.
2. Parallelism vs. Overhead
3. Data Loading Speed
4. I/O-bound vs. CPU-bound
5. Memory Considerations
6. GPU Utilization

*I tested with:* `num_workers=32`

*Test code:*

```
total_images = 0
s_t = time.time()
for batch in train_loader:
        # Move the batch to the GPU
        batch = [tensor.to(device) for tensor in batch]
        images, labels = batch
        # Get the number of images in the current batch
        num_images_in_batch = len(labels)  # Get the number of images in the batch
        total_images += num_images_in_batch  #
    print("Total number of images:", total_images)
    e_t = time.time()
    i_t = e_t - s_t
    print(f"Epoch Time: {i_t:.4f} seconds", flush=True)
```

*Output:*

```
Total number of batch loops: 32030
Total number of images: 1024953
Epoch Time: 1639.7372 seconds
```